# What tax forms are required for solo S corps in California?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, payroll-taxes, payroll

The FTB site only lists [Form 100S](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/business/types/corporations/s-corporations.html) as required filing.

However, the EDD site also [lists DE 34, DE 9, and DE 88](https://edd.ca.gov/en/Payroll_Taxes/Required_Filings_and_Due_Dates). Are these forms necessary for the solo owner-employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are payroll forms, similar to the Federal forms 940, 941, W2 and W3. Yes, they're all required.